# JPA Query Specification Date Comparator

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, specifications

I'm using `SpringBoot 2.2.6` and `JPA` and I want to do a query with multiple Criteria (with Dates).

Just for try I have do something like this (as read here):

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
....
Path<Date> entityDate = root.get("dataInserimento");
java.util.Date from = null;
java.util.Date to = null;
java.sql.Date ff = null;
java.sql.Date tt = null;
        try {
            from = localeIta.parse("2000/10/10");
            to = localeIta.parse("2020/10/10");
            ff = new java.sql.Date(from.getTime());
            tt = new java.sql.Date(to.getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) {}
predicates.add(builder.between(entityDate, ff, tt));
```

but doesn't work. If I use `java.util.Date` I get an error and even if I don't use `Path<Date>` to retrieve the Date to confront I obtain an error.

This way I haven't error at runtime but no result.

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2000, 10, 10, 00, 00, 00);
java.util.Date fromDate = calendar.getTime();

calendar.set(2020, 10, 10, 00, 00, 00);
java.util.Date toDate = calendar.getTime();

predicates.add(cb.between(root.get("dataInserimento"), fromDate, toDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I was wrong in another part of code, the full code is:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SearchCriteria {
 private String key;
 private Object value;
 private SearchOperation operation;

 public SearchCriteria(String key, Object value, SearchOperation operation) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.operation = operation;
 }
}
```

SearchOperation `Enum`:

```
public enum SearchOperation {
 GREATER_THAN,
 LESS_THAN,
 GREATER_THAN_EQUAL,
 LESS_THAN_EQUAL,
 NOT_EQUAL,
 EQUAL,
 MATCH,
 MATCH_END,
 BETWEEN_DATE,
 GREATER_THAN_DATE,
 LESS_THAN_DATE;
}
```

And the GenericSpecification:

```
public class GenericSpecification<T> implements Specification<T> {

 private SimpleDateFormat localeIta = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 private List<SearchCriteria> list;

 public GenericSpecification() {
    this.list = new ArrayList<>();
 }

 public void add(SearchCriteria criteria) {
    list.add(criteria);
 }

 @Override
 public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (SearchCriteria criteria : list) {
    switch(criteria.getOperation()) {
    ....
    case BETWEEN_DATE: {
       Path<Date> entityDate = root.get(criteria.getKey());
       predicates.add(builder.between(entityDate, getComparingDates((String[])criteria.getValue(), 0), getComparingDates((String[])criteria.getValue(), 1)));
      }
    break; /** I FORGET THIS BREAK **/
    }

 private java.sql.Date getComparingDates(String[] dates, int order) {
    java.sql.Date result = null;
    try {
        if (order == 0) {
            java.util.Date from = localeIta.parse(dates[0].toString());
            result = new java.sql.Date(from.getTime());
        } else {
            java.util.Date to = localeIta.parse(dates[1].toString());
            result = new java.sql.Date(to.getTime());
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now it works perfectly! Thank you